# 16 bit image compression with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to compress a 16 bit image with opencv. Basically I could do that, because the decompressed image looks like the same as the original one.

My problem is that while the type of input image is CV_16UC1, the decompressed image's type is CV_8UC3 and not CV_16UC1. So I lost my 16 bit information for each pixel what I need.

Based on the documentation I saw that if I set the decode flag to CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH then I could get a 16 bit result, but couldnt get it. This flag was CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR (=1) when I got a CV_8UC3 result.

Here is my code.

```
std::vector<int> compression_parameters;
compression_parameters.push_back(1);
compression_parameters.push_back(75);   

auto compressable = cv::Mat(cv::Size(w, h), CV_16UC1, (unsigned char*)input_data);

std::vector<uint8_t> compressed;
cv::imencode(".jpeg", compressable, compressed, compression_parameters);
auto size = compressed.size();

cv::Mat ImMat = cv::Mat(cv::Size(w, h), CV_16UC1);

std::vector<uint8_t> ImVec(compressed.begin(), compressed.begin() + size);
cv::imdecode(ImVec, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH, &ImMat);

auto orig_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(_compressable.data);
auto decom_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(ImMat.data);

// only compression error expected
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i, orig_ptr++, decom_ptr++)  
     std::cout << *orig_ptr << " " << *decom_ptr << "\n";
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: It is unsure that this possibility is supported. 16 bits grayscale is a not-so-usual format.

Comment: The JPEG encoder in OpenCV doesn't support anything other than 8bit data (it has no override of `isFormatSupported`), so `imwrite` automatically converts to `CV_8U` before saving. Why not try PNG instead, that should handle it.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly with the PNG encoder.
I just wanted to try the JPEG as well, didnt know about that its not supported.